# Custom UITextField delegate

Tags: ios, uitextfield, automatic-ref-counting

I have a `uitextfield` subclass and in the `init` method and `setDelegate` I have this:

```
- (void) setDelegate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>)paramDelegate{
    [super setDelegate:paramDelegate];

    MRAAdvancedTextFieldDelegate *limitedDelegate = [[MRAAdvancedTextFieldDelegate alloc] init];
    self.delegate = limitedDelegate;
}
```

I am using ARC, but this results in a BAD_ACCESS. Any ideas?

Comment: I gave an answer below, but actually realized I'm a little confused about what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to have two separate delegates? Or extend the UITextFieldDelegate protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write `self.delegate = limitedDelgate` within your `setDelegate:` method. This is exactly the same as calling `[self setDelegate:limiatedDelegate]`. Since you are within the `-setDelegate:` method itself, you are causing infitine recursion. Hope this helps!

EDIT: per your comment about your intention, override it like this:

```
- (void) setDelegate:(id<UITextFieldDelegate>)paramDelegate{
    MRAAdvancedTextFieldDelegate *limitedDelegate = [[MRAAdvancedTextFieldDelegate alloc] init];
    [super setDelegate:limitedDelegate];
}
```

But I don't believe it's a good idea to do this - you should have your client code pass in instances of your delegate instead.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I ensure that when I do someTextField.delegate in my view controller it won't set?

Comment: @MarioPen see my comment on your question. To suggest a further solution I'll need to understand more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want all delegate methods to be handled by a given class only, so as such I don't want to set the delegate for the field. Hence why I was overriding the setter.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.delegate = limitedDelegate;
```

is turned into

```
[self setDelegate:limitedDelegate];
```

by the compiler, resulting in an infinite loop. Solution: instead of using the property, use the instance variable instead in the custom setter method:

```
delegate = limitedDelegate;
```